# Where should I ask coding strategy questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, strategy

Very Simple...I have a question up in my mind about a coding design, I have the concepts of how to do it, but as I am not a pro programmer, I want to get the advice of experts on SO network for the best way to implement a solution for the problem I have to code to. So basically its about discussing a strategy of how can I design and implement the best solution, please note that the question and answer will have some code directions...where should I ask such kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is the place to ask software design questions.

From their [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - software requirements
> - software architecture and design
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - development methodologies and processes
> - software engineering management
> - quality assurance and testing
> - software licensing

Do go through the help center to find out the exact scope of the site before asking, though.